# XSLT : Group elements that are close to each other within a tag

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to group Consecutive tags within a group tag using xslt
for example :

```
 <description> aaaa </description>
 <description> ffff </description>
 <description> aaaa </description>
 <text> some text </text>
 <description> 586 </description>
 <description> Hello </description>
 <text> some text </text>
 <description> world </description>
```

the result should be something like this :

```
<group>
   <description> aaaa </description>
   <description> ffff </description>
   <description> aaaa </description>
</group>
<text> some text </text>
<group>
   <description> 586 </description>
   <description> Hello </description>
</group>
<text> some text </text>
<group>
   <description> world </description>
</group>
```

Comment: If you know you are looking for adjacent `description` elements then, in XSLT 1.0, use sibling recursion or use a key `<xsl:key name="adjacent-group" match="description[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::description]]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::description[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::description])][1])"/>`  and pull in the nodes using the `key` function.